# How to add axis with label attached to it for future reference?

Tags: python, matplotlib

One great thing I like is when I create a figure I can pass the name using `num` argument. If the figure exists, it grabs it, if not it creates it. However, when adding axes to the figure I don't see extension of this

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(num='Head Boundary')
ax = fig.subplots(no label can passed here :( )
# Nor here:
fig.add_axis 
fig.add_subplot
```

Additionally, when I recall the axes of a figure `fig.get_axes()`, I get them slapped in a list. What if I wanted a certain one with given label? Do I have to manually loop through them and check which one has the name I need?

Comment: You can do `ax.set_label("Axes name")` after you create it. However, I'm not sure why you would want to do that because you already have access to the axes object itself, `ax`

Comment: @DavidG I found the solution. Part of it is what you said `set_label("blah")` and the other part is `.findobj` method to which you can pass this label.